# Trying to bind a table from Northwind db to VB.NET solution

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, northwind

I'm trying to populate GridViews from specific datasets in the northwind sample database. I'm trying to use a specific entry in MSDN to acquire these tables but I'm having the worst time understanding what these terms within the code snippet are.

**MSDN**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx

GetData, connectionString, dataAdapter, SqlDataAdapter(), selectCommand, connectionString, commandBuilder, SqlCommandBuilder(), DataTable(), table.Locale, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Me.dataAdapter.Fill(), Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = Table, Me.dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader), Catch ex As SqlException

I'm quite new, but I'm knowledgeable enough to research the rest on my own. I just need to know enough to research how I should handle each bit. Feel free to send me to another link to get a better grasp of it!

Comment: A great many of those have entire pages of info on them at MSDN.  Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour] - this is very broad for SO; this isnt wiktionary

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you just need to do the following to access data and load it into a given GridView :

1. Open a connection to the data source (generally a `SqlConnection` or `OleDbConnection`).
2. Create a query to use to pull your data out (generally done through a `SqlCommand` or `OleDbCommand` object.
3. Execute your query and setting the results as the `DataSource` attribute of your GridView.
4. Call the `DataBind()` method for your GridView after setting the `DataSource` attribute to ensure the new data is bound properly.

This might look something like this :

```
' Build your connection '
Using connection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
    ' Open your connection '
    connection.Open()

    ' Build your SQL query '
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM YourTable"

    ' Build your SqlCommand to execute the query '
    Using command = new SqlCommand(sql,conn)
         ' Execute a reader (from the SqlCommand object) '
         Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
             ' Bind your reader data to your grid `
             YourGridView.DataSource = reader
             YourGridView.DataBind();
         End Using
    End Using
End Using
```